# React typescript - Cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Folder structure:

```
src
  - containers
    - Home.tsx
```

I want to lazy load, so I'm trying:

```
const Home = React.lazy(() => import('containers/Home'));
```

VS Code shows 'containers/Home' as incorrect and when hovering over it complains:

```
Cannot find module 'containers/Home' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I have paths set in  tsconfig as:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
    "modules/*": [
        "src/modules/*"
    ],
    "containers/*": [
        "src/containers/*"
    ]
}
```

Why does it not find `containers/Home` when importing using `React.lazy()`?

Answer (score 1):

set paths in tsconfig this way

```
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
    "@modules/*": [
        "src/modules/*"
    ],
    "@containers/*": [
        "src/containers/*"
    ]
}
```

and use it like this

```
const Home = React.lazy(() => import('@containers/Home'));
```

Comment: Thanks, half works. The key is the change in `paths`. Typescript still cannot find `import('@containers/Home')` though, but, it can find as I originally had it: `import('containers/Home')`